# Checking if API works

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am working in Xamarin, currently working on getting some data out of an API, but i am not sure how to check if i actually got through the login process. I used this code for the login process:

```
public async Task<Token> Login(){
    var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", 
    "password"));
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", 
     "********"));
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", 
    "********"));
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
    var weburl = "**********************";
    var response = await PostResponse<Token>(weburl, content);
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
    dt = DateTime.Today;
    response.Expire_Date = dt.AddSeconds(response.Expires_In);
    return response;
}
```

I tried to get some kind of response by making a simple toString method on the result:

```
var result = App.RestService.Login();
string a = result.ToString();
```

When i write out the a, i just get a System.Threading.Tasks.Task[Interpret.InterpretedObject] error, not much to go on..

The API should give a response of an errormsg and a long string of numbers and characters.

I guess the real question is: How do i get out the two messages that i need from my API?

PS. The constructor for the RestService:

```
public RestService()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded' "));
    }
```

I updated the solution to take care of the async problem, now i get an exception instead.

I call the async method like this:

```
public partial class DayView : ContentPage
{
    public DayView ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        getData();
    }

    public async void getData()
    {
        var result = await App.RestService.Login();
        string a = result.ToString();
        BindingContext = new Response(a);
    }
}
```

The app works now on my iphone, but i get a CertificateUnkown(TlsException), does this mean i have initiated first contact with my API?

Comment: You need to `await` the login call... `var result = await App.RestService.Login();`

Comment: I think you've beaten my to my answer by a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting a meaningful response, because `Login` is an async Task, and you treat it like a syncronous call, while you actually should await it:

```
var result = await App.RestService.Login();
```

Comment: Makes sense.. But the method tells me that the method is not async, 'consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'...

Comment: Does the method that i use the ToString method in have to be async aswell?

Comment: If the compiler tells you, that `App.RestService.Login` is not async, then that is not the login method you've shown us above, because that is clearly labelled as async. And don't do `async void`. Use `async Task` instead.

Comment: Well it is, i think they ment the method that i made the toString method call from, because my login method sure is async..